# На плоскости заданы множество точек и окружность радиусом R с центром в начале координат.Построить множество всех треугольников

Tags: c++

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с задачкой.
Условие : На плоскости заданы множество точек и окружность радиусом R с центром в начале координат. Построить множество всех треугольников с вершинами в заданных точках, имеющих непустое пересечение с окружностью.

Вот что выводит в таком виде , почему он мне не выводит координаты в ответ я не понимаю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.s если ошибки банальные и глупые извиняйте я только учусь :c

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <clocale>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct point {
    double x, y;
};
struct trg {
    point a, b, c;
};
const int nmax = 30;
bool peres(double r , trg t)
{
    return ((sqrt(t.a.x) + sqrt(t.a.y) > r * r) && (sqrt(t.b.x) + sqrt(t.b.y) < r * r)) || ((sqrt(t.a.x) + sqrt(t.a.y) > r * r) && (sqrt(t.c.x) + sqrt(t.c.y) < r * r)) || ((sqrt(t.b.x) + sqrt(t.b.y) > r * r) && (sqrt(t.c.x) + sqrt(t.c.y) < r * r));
}
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    point t[nmax];
    trg p[30];
    int np, nv, n, i, k, j;
    double r;
    trg tr;
    srand(time(0));
    do {
        cout << "Количество точек кратное 3 до " << nmax << " n=";
        cin >> n;
    } while (n < 2 || n>30);
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        t[i].x = rand() % 30 - 10;
        t[i].y = rand() % 30 - 10;
    }
    cout << "Введите радиус окружности\nR=";
    cin >> r;
    cout << "Координаты точек:\nX:";
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        cout << t[i].x << " ";
    cout << "\nY:";
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        cout << t[i].y << " ";
    nv = 0;
    np = 0;
    
    for (i = 1; i < n - 2; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < n - 1; j++) {
            for (k = j + 1; k < n; k++) {
                tr.a = t[i];
                tr.b = t[j];
                tr.c = t[k];
                if (peres(r, tr)) {
                    np++;
                    cout <<"np=" << np;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (np == 0) { cout << "нет треугольников пересекающихся с окружностью\n"; }
    else {
        cout << "Множество треугольников пересекающихся с окружностью:";
        for (i = 0; i < np - 1; i++) {
            cout << "[(" << p[i].a.x << ";" << p[i].a.y << ")" << "(" << p[i].b.x << ";" << p[i].b.y << ")" << "(" << p[i].c.x << ";" << p[i].c.y << ")]";
```

Comment: Потому что вы вовсе не заполняете массив `p`

Comment: а как мне его собсна заполнить 0_0

Comment: "Количество точек кратное 3" - заставляет задуматься надо ли перебирать все комбинации точек? Или надо точки разбить на непересекающиеся тройки?

Comment: Так вот этот кусок `if (peres(r, tr)) {...}` недоделан. Счётчик треугольников увеличиваете, так и сам треугольник нужно в p[] заносить

Comment: И функция peres, думаю, негодная. sqrt - что делает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не ошибся при составлении и решении квадратных уравнений, то примерно так...

```
inline double sq(double x) { return x*x; }

bool isSect(double x0, double y0, double x1, double y1, double r)
{
    double dx = x0 - x1, dy = y0 - y1;
    dx *= dx;
    dy *= dy;
    if (dx + dy == 0) return false;
    double det = (dx+dy)*sq(r) - sq(x1*y0 - x0*y1);


    if (det < 0) return false;
    double t1 = x0*(x0-x1) + y0*(y0-y1);
    double t2 = (t1 + sqrt(det))/(dx+dy);
    t1 = (t1 - sqrt(det))/(dx+dy);
    if (t1 >= 0 && t1 <= 1) return true;
    if (t2 >= 0 && t2 <= 1) return true;
    return false;
}

struct pnt
{
    int x, y;
};

void out(pnt a, pnt b, pnt c)
{
    cout << "[(" << a.x << "," << a.y
        << ")(" << b.x << "," << b.y
        << ")(" << c.x << "," << c.y << ")]\n";
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    vector<pnt> p;
    unsigned int n;
    double r;
    cout << "Points count: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Radius: ";
    cin >> r;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        pnt t;
        t.x = rand()%30 - 10;
        t.y = rand()%30 - 10;
        p.push_back(t);
        cout << "(" << t.x << ", " << t.y << ")\n";
    }

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        pnt a = p[i];
        for(unsigned int j = i+1; j < n; ++j)
        {
            pnt b = p[j];
            bool sectab = isSect(a.x,a.y,b.x,b.y,r);
            for(unsigned int k = j+1; k < n; ++k)
            {
                pnt c = p[k];
                if (sectab) out(a,b,c);
                else if (isSect(a.x,a.y,c.x,c.y,r)) out(a,b,c);
                else if (isSect(b.x,b.y,c.x,c.y,r)) out(a,b,c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется, упущен случай, когда ни одна вершина не входит в окружность, а пересечение по ребру

Comment: ... и случай когда треугольник содержит окружность целиком внутри себя.

Comment: @MBo А теперь сойдет? :)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Теперь вроде бы всё учтено?

Comment: @Harry Можно же дополнить. В этой "простой" задаче до 9 случаев [вообще рассматривают](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A8EJ.png). Но да, подход с пересчётом вершин "внутри" не подойдёт

Comment: Ой, вы уже поправили ;)

Comment: Стало лучше. У меня в голове такая идея: научиться измерять минимальное расстояние от отрезка до начала координат. Если для какой-то стороны, оно меньше радиуса, пересечение есть. Если все расстояния велики, проверяется ноль на принадлежность треугольнику. Должно быть проще.

Comment: @Harry спасибо большое!!!

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Вы меня натолкнули на оптимизацию :) Сейчас доделаю... А считать пересечение или считать расстояние — примерно все равно по сложности...